# Is there a fix to Windows 7 Explorer Rename (F2) - adding text to the end of a filename

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, rename

Pressing F2 on
Filename.ext
Explorer selects "Filename".
You want to add a text at the end of "Filename", like:
FilenameText.ext
so you press RightArrow.
The problem: the cursor moves to the right side of the dot, and you have to move the cursor back to the left side of the dot.
Expected: You want to type immediately after pressing the RightArrow.

Edit: User wants to display extensions (“Hide extensions for known file types” option is unchecked).

Comment: Ctrl-X Ctrl-V instead of right-arrow left-arrow?

Comment: Enable - 'Hide extensions for known file types'

Comment: Ah, @spikey_richie posted as a comment the key part of my answer while I was typing my answer...

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you hold down the <kbd>right arrow</kbd> key, so that you are at the end of the filename?  A faster approach would be to press the <kbd>End</kbd> key to get to the end of the editable text.

If you're not a programmer, sometimes you need to just accept the design of the software that people made, especially if using closed-source software (like Microsoft Windows Explorer).

However, there is a workaround that will probably accomplish what you've after.  If I recall correctly for Windows 7, start by going to Explorer and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> to show the Tools menu, and then choose “Folder Options”.

On the “Folder Options” screen, on the “View” tab, ensure the “Hide extensions for known file types” is checked.  (Then use Apply/OK button(s).)

The result will be the effect that you want.  Only the non-extension part of the filename will be what Explorer shows, so that will be the only part of the filename that is editable, so pressing <kbd>End</kbd> or holding down <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> will place the cursor in the exact right spot.

The thing is, though, if that box was unchecked, then you probably customized that since the operating system's default is to have that box checked.  So, you do have a choice.  You can either have the filename be shown fully, or have the filename editing act the way that you like.  At the time of this writing, I simply don't see a pre-built way for you to have it both ways.  (Such is the nature of limitations in software that you don't create/modify yourself.)